# Symfony - how to choose the right interface (type-hint) for symfony services?

Tags: php, symfony, namespaces

I often struggle with including oder guessing the right interface
to include a service. For Example, this is the recommend way to get a router.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class SomeService
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }
}
```

I think, what I get here is "vendor\symfony\routing\Router.php".
But class Router implements RouterInterface, RequestMatcherInterface.
Not UrlGeneratorInterface!

I do not understand the logic behind this. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is where it might be best to roll up your sleeves and dive into the source code.  The generator interface provides a generate method and it is what is used most of the time.  Your $router variable really should be called $generator.  The thing is, the RouterInterface extends both UrlGeneratorInterface as well as UrlMatcherInterface.  So it can both generate and match.  I tend to use the RouterInterface just because having a router object seems easier to understand.  Even though I very seldom need the match functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces

Practice is in fact to alias the interface that you type-hint, to a class that you want injected. So if you want different class than `Router` to be injected, in `services.yml` do:

```
// services.yml
services:
    App\Util\Router: ~

    Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface: '@App\Util\Router'
```

> As long as there is only one class implementing the interface and that class is part of the same namespace configuring the alias is not mandatory and Symfony will automatically create one.

Why your case works? Inheritance.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouterInterface.php

`interface RouterInterface extends UrlMatcherInterface, UrlGeneratorInterface`

Comment: Close but not quite.  "bin/console debug:container | grep Url" shows that UrlGeneratorInterface and UrlMatcherInterface both have aliases explicitly defined as router.default.  Which is why injecting works but you always get a router object regardless.  Bit of a hack really.  And, in spite of what the docs imply, this whole thing about having one and only one service defined for a given interface does not always work as expected.